# Assign values to an "offset" diagonal in a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

If I have a matrix `x` of arbitrary dimensions, for this example:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    0    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    0    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    0
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

and I want to change the 0s to 1s starting from a certain column and then moving one down and one right until the end last column. So if I start from column `[,3]` the change would result in

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    1    0    0
[2,]    0    0    0    1    0
[3,]    0    0    0    0    1
[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

I thought maybe something like this `x[,3:ncol(x)][1:ncol(x)] <- 1` but that gave me

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    0    0    1    0    0
[2,]    0    0    1    0    0
[3,]    0    0    1    0    0
[4,]    0    0    1    0    0
[5,]    0    0    1    0    0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We could use `row/column` indexing.  Suppose if we the arbitrary column from which we start is 'n', create a sequence from that column to the last column ('n1'), `cbind` that will the sequence of 'n1', use that for subsetting 'x' and replace the values with 1.

```
 n <- 3
 n1 <- n:ncol(x)
 x[cbind(seq(n1), n1)] <- 1
 x
 #     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
 #[1,]    0    0    1    0    0
 #[2,]    0    0    0    1    0
 #[3,]    0    0    0    0    1
 #[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
 #[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

Or another option is

```
 x[seq(n1), n1] <- diag(ncol(x)-n+1)
```

Or using `sparseMatrix`

```
 library(Matrix)
 n <- 3
 rN <- 5
 cN <- 5
 n1 <- n:cN
 s1 <- sparseMatrix(seq_along(n1), n1, x=1)
 as.matrix(rbind(s1,matrix(0, nrow=rN-nrow(s1), ncol=ncol(s1))))
```

#### Update

On a slightly bigger dataset

```
m1 <- matrix(0, nrow=1e6, ncol=100)
system.time({
  n <- 3
  n1 <- n:ncol(m1)
  m1[cbind(seq(n1), n1)] <- 1
 })
#  user  system elapsed 
# 0.117   0.096   0.212 
which(m1==1, arr.ind=TRUE)[,2]
#[1]   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21
#[20]  22  23  24  25  26  27  28  29  30  31  32  33  34  35  36  37  38  39  40
#[39]  41  42  43  44  45  46  47  48  49  50  51  52  53  54  55  56  57  58  59
#[58]  60  61  62  63  64  65  66  67  68  69  70  71  72  73  74  75  76  77  78
#[77]  79  80  81  82  83  84  85  86  87  88  89  90  91  92  93  94  95  96  97
#[96]  98  99 100
```

#### data

```
 x <- matrix(0, 5, 5)
```

Answer (score 5):

You may also use `row` and `col`:

```
start_col <- 3
m[row(m) + start_col - 1 == col(m)] <- 1

m    
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]    0    0    1    0    0
# [2,]    0    0    0    1    0
# [3,]    0    0    0    0    1
# [4,]    0    0    0    0    0
# [5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

Where `m` is:

```
m <- matrix(0, ncol = 5, nrow = 5)
```

Answer (score 1):

A vectorized solution is not required if individual entries of a matrix are modified. In such cases, a `for` loop can be used efficiently:

```
m <- matrix(0,ncol=5, nrow=5)
loop_end <- min(ncol(m), nrow(m) + 2)
for (i in 3:loop_end){m[i-2,i] <- 1}

#> m
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
#[1,]    0    0    1    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    0    1    0
#[3,]    0    0    0    0    1
#[4,]    0    0    0    0    0
#[5,]    0    0    0    0    0
```

Comment: Yes, now it works, and the timings are slightly better than me.